# Authentication cookie sharing between ASP WebForms and ASP.NET Core MVC app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, webforms, .net-4.5, .net-6.0

I have 2 ASP.NET applications, one is ASP.NET WebForms on .NET 4.5, and the other in an ASP.NET Core 6 app.

The connection of the user is done on the application in WebForms. When the user is connected, I have to redirect him to the ASP.NET Core application and it must automatically identify the user who has connected.

I use an authentication cookie on the webforms application with `FormsAuthenticationTicket`.

Is it possible to share this cookie between the 2 applications?

If I ask you this question it's because I'm stuck.

I found some resources about sharing the authentication cookie between ASP.NET MVC and Core applications but I can't find anything for Webforms applications

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can share the cookie between the asp.net application and asp.net core application. [The data protection stack allows sharing Katana cookie authentication and ASP.NET Core cookie authentication tickets](https://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security/data-protection/compatibility/cookie-sharing.html).

You need add code like below:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddAuthentication();
    ...
}

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    DataProtectionProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\shared-auth-ticket-keys\"))
});
```

And in your webform application.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
    CookieName = ".AspNetCore.Cookies",
    // CookiePath = "...", (if necessary)
    // ...
    TicketDataFormat = new AspNetTicketDataFormat(
        new DataProtectorShim(
            DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\shared-auth-ticket-keys\"))
            .CreateProtector("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware",
            "Cookies", "v2")))
});
```

For more details you can check the link I provided.

And you also can find the refer the [webform repo](https://github.com/VdoCipher/sample-asp-net-web-forms/tree/65c7c471040ab0fd31996b14ea2c4f7d875ca736).

Comment: To use `AspNetTicketDataFormat` I need to install `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Interop` but the package is deprecated, so NuGet doesn't install it ...
Is there a way to install it by force?

Comment: @sylvaing I can install it in my local, have you [try to use command to install it](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Interop/2.2.0-preview3-35497).

Comment: I still have this mistake...
`The combination of parameters provided to this OData endpoint is no longer supported`
I don't understand, this package is compatible with versions 4.6.1 and higher.
I tried with several versions and I have the same error.
Yes, I have tried in command line and different versions of the package.
Any idea ? 
And i created a new project and same error ...

Comment: While searching for hours I found the solution ... The packages did not want to install because ... I was using visual studio community 2013. By using visual studio community 2022 everything works perfectly